# Python filter over a function with two arguments?

Tags: python, list

What I'm trying to do is take a list and filter it based on comparisons of adjacent list members. Namely, something like this

```
filter(lambda x,y: x != y, someList)
```

to get rid of duplicate elements right next to each other. I can easily implement this other ways, but started out trying to do it with a list reduction/filter and am stubborn enough to want to keep trying until I figure it out. I am still not that experienced in python, but I feel like there is something like this that I am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: What other ways have you considered? It'd help if you post those (and is `someList` actually a `list` or sequence or some arbitrary iterable) etc... (desired input and output samples would also be good)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return imap(next, imap(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))
```

**Source:** [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/index.html), [9.7.2. Recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

There's a wealth of great stuff in [**`itertools`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for efficient looping.

Answer (score 3):

For consecutive elements (duplicate elements) then:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> items = 'aaaabbdeeeeefg'
>>> ''.join(k for k, g in groupby(items))
'abdefg'
```